# Mail.app rules not triggering

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail, applescript, email-filter

I have a mail.app rule set up to run an applescript when incoming emails come in with a certain subject, but it does not trigger. I see the emails in my inbox, and the rule is activated, but it does not trigger. I don't think it's a problem with my applescript, because I set the rule to also bounce icon in dock, and it doesn't do that. Any suggestions?